# Can I make Vim add `pack/*/start/*` directories to `runtimepath` without restarting?

Tags: packages

Let's say that I've got a package set up like this:

```
~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/
                         vim-unimpaired/
                         vim-surround/
```

When Vim starts up, it automatically adds the `vim-surround` and `vim-unimpaired` directories to my `runtimepath`.

While I've got Vim running, let's say that I add the `vim-fugitive` plugin to the `start` directory, making my package look like this:

```
~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/
                         vim-unimpaired/
                         vim-surround/
                         vim-fugitive/
```

Can I make Vim check the `start` directory again and add any paths to the `runtimepath` that are not already present there?

I understand that if I start a new Vim session, then my `runtimepath` will contain all three plugins. I'm curious to know if there's a way of updating the `runtimepath` without having to restart Vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`:packloadall!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Apackloadall):

> Load all packages in the "start" directory under each entry in `'packpath'`
>
> [..]
>
> This is normally done automatically during startup, after loading your .vimrc
>   file.  With this command it can be done earlier.
>
> [..]
>
> Packages will be loaded only once.  After this command
>   it won't happen again.  When the optional ! is added
>   this command will load packages even when done before.

There's also the [`:packadd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Apackadd) command, but that will only load from `pack/*/opt`, not `pack/*/start`.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! I already knew about the `:packadd` command and I misunderstood the `:packloadall` command, thinking that it did the equivalent of `:packadd ALL` (that command doesn't actually exist). Now that I've re-read the docs for `:packloadall` I wonder how I missed it.